# Using filesort in simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

I have very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `navigation` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Название ссылки',
  `priority` tinyint(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Параметр сортировки'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

with only 41 rows. Also I have very simple query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT t.id, t.parent_id, t.title, t.priority FROM navigation t ORDER BY t.priority ASC;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   41 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I to avoid using `filesort`? Or is it impossible?
I have read a lot of topics on SO, but couldn't understand right answer.
Thank you.

Comment: With only 41 rows, why do you care?

Comment: Because I have now only 41 rows, but in production there are a lot of rows. And production server (MySQL) also has using filesort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I to avoid using filesort? Or is it impossible? I have read a lot of topics on SO, but couldn't understand right answer.

You would need an index over the `priority` column:

```
ALTER TABLE navigation ADD INDEX (priority);
```

However, the chances are that MySQL will calculate that using such an index to sort the results will ultimately be more expensive than a `filesort` (since the former will involve sequentially reading the index file in order to perform random I/O into the table, whereas the latter will involve sequentially reading the table and performing an in memory sort on the results).  You can override this assessment with an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/index-hints.html):

```
SELECT   t.id, t.parent_id, t.title, t.priority
FROM     navigation t FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (priority)
ORDER BY t.priority ASC;
```

A [covering index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) would altogether avoid the need to read into the table and thus could immediately return results merely from walking sequentially through the index file; it would therefore likely be selected by the query optimiser without further hinting:

```
ALTER TABLE navigation ADD INDEX(priority, id, parent_id, title);
```

Which approach is right for you will depend on your application's requirements, but remember Knuth's maxim: "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*".

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a filesort, most of the times you should be adding an index. In your case that would mean an index on the `priority` column. You can do this as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `navigation` ADD INDEX (`priority`);
```

Note that even with this index it is still possible that a filesort is used as that might actually be faster than using the index. With 41 rows this could be the case, even with an index defined.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/) `filesort` occurs everytime you sort on an unindexed column. It has nothing to do with actual sorting taking place in the file system.
With the description in [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726677/621519) you should get rid of it.